# How to test all environment configurations for DB scripts in lower environments

Tags: oracle, testing, scripting, environment

I need to figure out how to test all environment configurations in lower environments before going to production env.

Sometimes, my db scripts work fine in dev and test but then when I get to prod, i start seeing some issues. So is there a way to test the DB configuration file for all environments (dev, test, preprod, prod, etc) prior to getting to PROD?

Comment: What are the issues you're running into? We cannot help with a problem that we do not understand. 

You can set up different cases within a script so that it behaves differently depending on the environment, but we need to know more about the issues you're facing to be able to help with them.

Comment: @cdb_dba The issue is my build broke when I ran it in production due to a few scripts that consisted of aspects that were designed to exist only in lower environment. That's why I want to know if there's a way to test all scripts in lower environments but targeting my production environment?

Comment: @samg This is an important question but not a good fit for Stack Overflow, where the Q&A format favors right-or-wrong answers.  Avoiding environmental differences is a large and difficult topic.  The answers depend entirely on the languages, processes, and configurations you use at your organization.  I'd say in general there are two approaches to this problem: 1) try to harmonize the environments and reduce the number of builds, or 2) implement automated unit testing, build frequently, and have a large test suite to catch common issues.  I prefer #2, but it requires time and discipline.

Comment: @JonHeller, thanks for your feedback. So the build consists of DB scripts only, and I cannot build production environment frequently. Production gets build based on releases take months to complete. However, prior to running the DB build on production, I would like to test it to make sure that there shouldn't be any issues if ran in production.

Comment: @samg It's difficult to give specific advice, this problem happens in so many ways.  You either need to be reactive (every time there's a failure, write a test for it), or proactive (have DBAs and admins compare environments and avoid differences if possible).  The problem with only deploying every few months is that it's impossible to get good at something that only happens every few months.  You don't have to deploy to prod every day, but deploying to lower environments frequently may improve the entire process.

Comment: @JonHeller, so we do build lower environments frequently but the issue we ran into is that we have some testing schemas in lower environment that do not exist in prod and some of our scripts handled these testing schemas so when we tried to deploy our production build, it broke because of these schemas. That's why I wanted to know if there's a way to test all environment configurations in lower environments prior to going to prod. Hope that makes more sense?

Comment: @samg There's still the question of what you want to compare.  For example, some of the environmental differences I've ran into in the past were: database version/edition/platform, v$parameter differences, ASM vs. file system, hardware differences (memory, CPU, etc), OS differences (version, configuration), network configuration, database object differences (tables, views, directories, roles, users, etc.).  Can you narrow down precisely what kind of differences you're looking for?

Comment: @JonHeller, I would say mainly db objects/scripts at this point